# how to express period until event

Tags: time, periods

So let's say today is Monday and there will be a party on Friday.

How should I say when the party is:

> the party is in 3 days

or

> the party is in 4 days?

Also, is this sequence of time periods correct:

- > in 2 days
- > in 1 day (the day after tomorrow)
- > tomorrow?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are the asterisks signifying?

Comment: it's quoted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If today is Monday:

- "In one day" = "tomorrow" = Tuesday
- "In two days" = Wednesday
- "In three days" = Thursday
- "In four days" = Friday

... and so on.

Comment: Recently people have started saying "5 more sleeps!"

Answer (score 1):

When you say that something will happen "in X time," you're saying that the duration from now until then is X. If the current day is Monday, and the event is on Friday, four days will elapse between now and the event (Monday to Tuesday (1), Tuesday to Wednesday (2), Wednesday to Thursday (3), and Thursday to Friday (4)).

Saying "the party is in one day" is the same as saying "the party is tomorrow."